# Push Notification for iphone

Tags: c#, iphone, windows-services

i want to develope a windows service which sends a push notification to iphone for content update. is there any sample code or project available to do so and is there any API or helper class to implement push notification.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/) on Sending Push Notifications with c# and asp.net. This should give you the basic knowledge you need, then you can create your service with a little bit of c# magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through follwowing two links 
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services
and
http://www.macoscoders.com/2009/05/17/iphone-apple-push-notification-service-apns/

Hope this helps.

Comment: @james if it really helped just upvote the answer so that it would help others as well...

Answer (score 0):

yeah go for [apnssharp](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp), free, opensource , works a treat

Comment: i downloded the dll but it requires a .p12 certificate . i got the developer certificate but it is .cer i want .p12 how to convert it to .p12???? as i didnt have any mac system. is there any way to do this with any tools in windoes system

Comment: pretty sure there could be , but you may need to have a look on Google, i did mine on OSX so i cant help, sorry. Any way you go about it this, it will need doing - so hit up them search engines

Answer (score 0):

got the right certificate and how push notification working for me for iphone but i found that there is a small bug in apns sharp lib. after fixing that i can send notification to iphone